# How to know whether we are in a console or a windowed app?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

Context : programming a c/c++ win32-mfc library

How to know whether we are in a console or a windowed app?

Comment: If this is a library, why should you need to know?

Comment: a library shouldn't worry where it's used. the application should worry. that's the idealistic view, there are exceptions. but exceptions to that rule are rare i would say :)

Comment: Exceptions exist to communicate errors to the code calling the library ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can determine if there is a console currently attached to the process by calling the win32 function [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175(VS.85).aspx). If it returns NULL then there is no console attached to the process. However this will not necessarily tell you if you are running in a windowed app or not. For example I could have a windowed app that uses [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx) on start-up to allocate a console for debug output in which case you would have both at the same time. The other problem I can see with what you describe is an application might have no windows and no console attached (A windows service for example).

I'm going to have to agree with litb and Martin on this one as well. If your library needs to know this then it probably isn't decoupled enough. If you are using this to determine where to send debug output for example the best approach would be to use cout or cerr and let the application that is using the library deal with redirecting the stream to where it wants it.

Comment: Ok, so the question was "bad-conditionned"; an approximative method based on GetConsoleWindow would be using EnumThreadWindows to test on each window if it is a console window, comparing its hwnd to the one obtained through GetConsoleWindow.

Comment: `GetConsoleWindow` won't work if process was started with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag — and that's exactly how Qt usually starts processes. With that flag, you have invisible console: files `CONOUT$` and `CONIN$` exist (and work), `AllocConsole()`/`AttachConsole()` fail, `GetConsoleCP` returns non-zero value, etc; but `GetConsoleWindow()` returns `NULL`, because there is no console *window*. So to test if there is an attached console, `!!GetConsoleCP()` works more reliably: and coincidentally, that's what Cygwin uses.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain about this (without having tried it myself) but you can call the GetStartupInfo function which completes a STARTUPINFO structure.

Perhaps console and windows apps set the STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW flag of the dwFlags member differently and you could distinguish them like that.

As mentioned in the comments of your question, it is usually not a good sign when a library needs to know such things - the more decoupled you can keep it the better.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Testing for the STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW is unreliable, unless you control starting the console application yourself. It's perfectly valid to create a process with CREATE_NEW_WINDOW, STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW and SW_HIDE.