# golang: optional console on windows

Tags: windows, go

I am writing a service program which is expected to run in background.  On Windows it will open a console window when run.  I want it to go to background directly without that console window, so I used the `-ldconf "-H=windowsgui"` option, which worked as expected.

However, there is a catch. The program has a command line option `-help`, which output command line usage in the console.  If I use `-H=windowsgui`, the help text is NOT printed even I start it in cmd.exe prompt.

It seems that the `windowsgui` option is not what I want. Is there anyway that the `-help` still works at commant line, and the console window will not persist if the program runs normally.  I do not care if there is a console window pops up, provided that it disappears shortly without user intervention. i.e. I want a way on windows which is similar to the **`&`** operator on Linux.

P.S. if provided solution uses any other tools, I want that tool to be a Windows component, not any 3rd-party program. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743217/printing-output-to-a-command-window-when-golang-application-is-compiled-with-ld